# Access data inside mounted VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create simple app with Vuejs that will check length of title tag (px).

Inside mounted I set the default value for title and run check length of default title tag but it return 0. When I change value of input, it work fine.

Here is my code. Link: https://codepen.io/mrtienhp97/pen/LeOzGa

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
   <input v-model="title" @input="titleCheck()">

  <div id="title-preview">{{title}}</div>

  <div class="message">{{message}}</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#title-preview {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: '',
    message: ''
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
      this.title = "Default Title";
      var title_width = document.getElementById("title-preview").offsetWidth;
      this.message = title_width + 'px';
    });
  },
  methods: {
    titleCheck: function() {
      var title_width = document.getElementById("title-preview").offsetWidth;
      this.message = title_width + 'px';
    }
  }
})
```

Can anyone help me correct it?

Comment: The reason is that the whole mounted() is happening before the rendering of the page. You should delay it somehow. I'm still trying to figure out a good answer though.

Answer (score 5):

You had the right idea in the `mounted` event to use the `$nextTick` to make sure the view was updated before getting the width, but you want to do that every time by making it part of `titleCheck`.  Here's what you can change to get it working:

1. Add a `ref` attribute to `title-preview` so you don't need to use `document.getElementById` (nothing wrong with it, but I prefer to let `Vue` do that for me)

`<div id="title-preview" ref="titleRef">{{title}}</div>`

2. Change `titleCheck` to use `$nextTick` as well as the `$refs` to get `title-preview`:

```js
titleCheck: function() {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    var title_width = this.$refs.titleRef.offsetWidth;
    this.message = title_width + 'px';
  });
}
```

3. You can simplify your `mounted` event to set the title and then call your `titleCheck` method:

```js
mounted: function() {
  this.title = "Default Title";
  this.titleCheck();
}
```

This should get you what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Patrick, it work if i add static data to title. But when i try to set dynamic title by getting data with axios( in `mounted`, i add these code `axios.get('request url')...` and `this.title = response.data` ), message return 0. I know my "axios" code is right because i can see value in input. Thank you

Comment: Had to tell without seeing your `axios` callback, but I suspect the `this` you're using to set `this.title` is not the Vue instance.  Trying saving the instance (`var vm = this;`) in a variable before calling axios and then in the `axios` callback, use `vm.title = response.data`.

Comment: @PatrickSteele I've the same issue. Saving the instance (var vm = this; ) works for me. Can you please explain this behavior?